# Dynamic Templates using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm following this Blog post < http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/> to understand the loading of dynamic templates using Angular JS in the same view. Now my requirement is slightly different where the dynamic template needs to be loaded in the button click and not in the container div as suggested in the Blog Post. I am  stuck to figure out as to how to do this. Can somebody help ? Pl read through the blog post or leave your comment in case you need more clarity

Comment: I think you just chose a wrong path to do this. If you need some dynamicness in a button ng-click, just make a controller method `handleClick`, and call it inside `ng-click="handleClick()". Inside that method you can do whatever you need to do

Comment: can you add a fiddle explaining the same. I'm failing after using ng-click as well :( guess I m going wrong somewhere

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here's a fiddle of how you might call different functions inside a click handler, dependant on some variable. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5291/

Comment: That's absolutely solving the prob

Comment: I think this [dynamicTemplate service](https://github.com/BurakAkyildiz/angularJs-dynamic-conditional-templates) helpfull for this case.